# Uploading image files to Django site on Linode

Tags: django, file-upload

I am setting up a Django site on Linode with Debian 6 and cannot get the image uploads to work. I have the upload target set in the model and my settings.py file is configured and can save the model with the file selected with no problem but the image never get written to the directory on my server. I think it may be a problem with permissions but cannot figure out how to fix it or find any solutions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to put up more information. Is the folder you are trying to upload to owned by the same user running apache/uwsgi? What are your MEDIA_ROOT/STATIC_ROOT set to in settings.py? How are you uploading files? Through django-admin? With a FileField in your model?

Comment: My target folder is owned by the root account, how can I find the user running my apache/wsgi process? I am using the ImageField in my model and the CSS in my static directory is functioning and set up similarly to the media directory. I think it is the ownership problem as you suggested.

Comment: hopefully apache is running as it's own user, and not root, so that might be the problem. You can check what user is running apache using 'htop' or just 'top'.

Comment: It looks like apache is running as user www-data. I have changed the ownership of the media directory recursively to www-data but still no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have the proper enctype set in my form element to handle files.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```